# writing implementation of function inside an abstract class

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it ok to write the implementation of a function inside an abstract class?

I want to have an abstract class that each of my components will extend so they will have some shared behaviour, so is it ok to have something like(simple example):

```
export abstract class SharedBehaviour {
    public helloWorld() {
        console.log("hello world");
    }
} 

export class MyComponent extends SharedBehaviour {
    public someMethod() {
        this.helloWorld();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's fine to do this, but maybe mark your `helloWorld` method as `protected` and use `super` to call it. Because then it's only accessible for classes that extend your abstract class and it's easier to see that `helloWorld` belongs to the parent class.

Comment: In addition, your subclass should call super() in its constructor.

Comment: I assume you have read the [documentation for `abstract` classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes). You must have missed the second sentence, which says **an abstract class may contain implementation details for its members**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Is it ok to write the implementation of a function inside an abstract class?

Yes. Abstract classes are free to have *non abstract methods* that provide shared code for all child classes.

To have *zero* implementation you would use *interfaces*.

Comment: *To have zero implementation you would use interfaces.* Not necessarily. You could also have only abstract methods in your abstract class.